# Why does this threading code not terminate?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I'm experimenting with Threading and Exceptions under C# .Net 4.5 and i somehow created an infinite loop without using for, while, do-while or recursion. If I excute/debug this code in Visual Studio, VS is stopping at every Exception (I keep hitting Continue).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += unhandledException;
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { throw new Exception("Thread.Start (ThreadID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ")"); })).Start();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(_ => { throw new Exception("ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (ThreadId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ")"); }));
    Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("Task.Run (" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ")"); });

    if (Debugger.IsAttached) Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void unhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unhandeled {0}:\t{1}", e.ExceptionObject.GetType().Name, (e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message);
}
```

When I run this application without VS, Windows terminates the program because it’s not responding.
So, what’s going on here? Why do this exceptions not appear only once?

Comment: Perhaps it does not terminate because you have the debugger attached, but not pressed the return key (`Console.ReadLine();`)?

Comment: Is this a console application?

Comment: @stakx: I can’t press enter, because VS keeps pausing/interrupting the process. But if I run it without VS, it doesn’t terminate on its own either.

Comment: @Gusdor: yes it’s a console application.

Comment: I've just tried your code and it runs fine. VS breaks on the two exceptions, and running externally just crashes on the first exception as you would expect.

Comment: that’s strange. (that’s what I would expect too)

Answer (score 0):

The Thrown setting on Debug -> Exceptions dialog (Ctrl + Alt + E) under Common Language Runtime Exceptions category might be selected. Try turning it off

[image]

Comment: That seems to make the `Task.Run` exception to disappear. Other then that no changes.  But technical I’m not trying to solve this problem, I’m trying to understand what’s going on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use a throw a new exception every time you create a new thread which causes the next thread to call on a new exception which calls a new exception on the next thread and so on.

From what I've understood you want to throw a new exception of your own type in a new thread and handle that.

What we need to do then is to bind our delegate to the waitcallback method instead of binding a new exception to it.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += unhandledException;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(_ => unhandledException("something", new UnhandledExceptionEventArgs("exception", true) )));
//we bind the unhandledException delegate to it instead of a throwing new exception
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { new Exception("Thread.Start (ThreadID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ")"); })).Start();
Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("Task.Run (" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ")"); });
if (Debugger.IsAttached) Console.ReadLine();
```